# PHPUnit :: get message: OK, but incomplete or skipped tests! without any information where is happen

Tags: php, phpunit

Get message:

**OK, but incomplete or skipped tests!**

without any information where is happen.
Only the: ..I........

How can i find where is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The output indicates that your third test case is incomplete. Try running phpunit with the --verbose flag to output more information.

Comment: thanks, there was a problem with the setting and --verbose helped me fix it!

Comment: Thanks for a dynamic solution! It also helps me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i had an echo call in a test that passed without any assertions. The test passed, after removing the echo. (didn't get any info upon passing --verbose to the test runner)

Answer (score -1):

My one test had this:

```
$this->markTestSkipped();
```

Hence it was skipped.