# PHPUnit skips all tests

Tags: phpunit

When I attempt to run PHPUnit, all tests are skipped immediately - there is no error or anything. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
[vagrant@vagrant selenium]$ phpunit .
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /applications/selenium/phpunit.xml

SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS

Time: 61 ms, Memory: 5.50Mb

OK, but incomplete or skipped tests!
Tests: 47, Assertions: 0, Skipped: 50.
```

My `phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    colors="true"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    backupGlobals="false"
    bootstrap="bootstrap.php">
    <php>
        <const name="BASE_URL" value="http://localhost" />
        <const name="SCREENSHOT_PATH" value="/tmp/selenium" />
        <const name="SCREENSHOT_URL" value="http://localhost/screenshots" />
        <const name="COVERAGE_URL" value="http://localhost/remote/codeCoverage" />
    </php>
    <selenium>
        <browser browser="*firefox"/>
    </selenium>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found this (searching for "skipped all tests" didn't return this result apparently)

[PHPUnit :: get message: OK, but incomplete or skipped tests! without any information where is happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708539/phpunit-get-message-ok-but-incomplete-or-skipped-tests-without-any-informa)

Which suggests I use `phpunit --verbose` and got the following messages for each test case:

`Could not connect to the Selenium Server on localhost:4444.`

So I guess that's where my problem lies now.