# PHPUnit always sets tests to "skipped"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I'm facing a strange problem with PHPUnit and the Selenium extension: I installed the most recent (stable) version of both via Composer. After that I started with a simple test class:

```
<?php
class TestLogin extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase {
    public function setUp() {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://dev.mydomain.com:10088/');
    }

    public function testHasLoginForm() {
        $this->url('user/login');
        $email = $this->byName('email');
        $password = $this->byName('password');
        $this->assertEquals('', $email->value());
        $this->assertEquals('', $password->value());
    }

    public function testSomething() 
    {
        $this->assertEquals('x', 'y');
    }
}
```

Now, when I run the test via

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php --testsuite Test --debug TestLogin.php
```

PHPUnit reports

```
Starting test 'TestLogin::testHasLoginForm'.
S
Starting test 'TestLogin::testSomething'.
S
```

Does anyone know why both tests are marked as "skipped"? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This problem has already been solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111988/phpunit-skips-all-tests

Answer (score 0):

I have zero experience with PHPUnit, but based on other test runners I have used in the past, you will get a Skip error usually in the case when your setup()  ( or @Before annotated method)  throws and exception/error which can break the test so that it never gets to the actual test method and therefore is "skipped".